# Forecasting with gaps in time series

Tags: tableau-api

Hi I'm trying to use the built in forecasting function in tableau and I think it's greyed out because my timeseries values have gaps.  Basically there are hours during the day when nothing happened in my data, so nothing got recorded.  I'm trying to build a forecast but my data jumps to the 2nd hour, then has results for each hour up to the 6, and jumps to the 9th.  I know in ssrs I would try left joining the sql query I'm using as a datasource to a derived field with all 24 hours.  I was hoping there was a slicker trick in tableau.  All help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: did the answer help? do you still miss something?

Answer (score 0):

Without having your worksheet, I'm not sure if it could be helpful, but have you already tried [this quick fix](http://kb.tableau.com/articles/issue/forecast-option-not-available) suggested by Tableau?

Basically you should use discrete measures and using the "Fill missing values with zeroes" option.